# XPath accounting non-existent nodes

Tags: php, xpath

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="post">
                     <p class="imgcontent">
                  <img src="hello.jpg"/>
                      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
                     <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
                    <p class="imgcontent">
          <img src="hello1.jpg"/>
                     </p>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Here is my XPATH:

```
//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]//@src
```

Here is the result:

```
 [0] => hello.jpg
 [1] => hello1.jpg
```

What i'd like is:

```
[0] => hello.jpg
[1] => ""
[2] => hello1.jpg
```

As you can see, the code should have 3 array positions since there was 3 "post" class divs.

I understand that this might not be possible using XPATH, however maybe there is a PHP solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how to do it on PHP:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($file);
$XPath = new DOMXPath($document);
$Query = '//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]';

$posts = $XPath->query($Query);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if($XPath->evaluate("//p//@src", $post))
    {
        $return[] = $XPath->evaluate("//p//@src", $post)->item(0);
    }else{
        $return[] =  "";
    }
}
```

Comment: its accounting for all indexes however no data is showing. Maybe we need to add a `nodeValue` somewhere? I tried after `item(0)` but that didnt do it. Also, I am using loadHTMLFile since its requesting a net web address. Does that make a difference? Lastly, youll see i added a wrapper p tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it will appear in php but following xpath

```
//div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post" and not(.//@src)] | //div[@class="content"]//div[@class="post"]//@src
```

seems to return desired data